# wordpress polylang Custom Select Query

Tags: sql, wordpress, polylang

I'm trying to translate this

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_TYPE_SLUG',
    'lang' => 'en',    // use language slug in the query
    // 'lang'           => '',      // query posts in all languages
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
));
```

into a Custom Select Query. I tried

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM $wpdb->posts, meta_value as meta_value_pl WHERE ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'YOUR_CUSTOM_TYPE_SLUG')
```

But with no luck. Can someone help ? Thanks !

Comment: Does your wp_query worked ? try debug with `var_dump($loop->request);` also polylang [docs](https://polylang.pro/doc/developpers-how-to/) would be much helpful, make sure your language is enable

Comment: Yes, my Custom Query work fine, it's just not filtering the language. I couldn't find any thing about Custom Select Query on the polylang doc, only the classic wp query that you can see there.

Comment: try with documented and then copy the polylang part and add it in your custom query

Comment: I'm sorry @Noman, I don't know what you mean by trying with documented. I tried with : " WHERE ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'  AND $wpdb->posts.lang = 'nl')" but without success. If I don't filter by posts.lang, I have post in both languages, and if I do, I get nothing. I wonder how polylang flag the post language.